# how to do regression in python via xarray?

Tags: python, regression, python-xarray

I am trying to do a regression day by day with my time series data X and Y respectively, which regression previous date's X data by current date's Y value. X is a 3-D data array with dimension date, stock and factor, Y is a 2-D data array with dimension date and stock. Can anybody help tell me how to do it with an efficient way?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import os
import warnings
from functools import reduce
import math as mt
import statsmodels.api as sm
from lib.gftTools import gftIO
import datetime
import logging

time = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', freq='D', periods=365)
X = xr.DataArray(
    np.random.randn(365, 10, 3), [('date', time), ('stock', list('abcdefghij')),
                                  ('factor', list('xyz'))])

Y = xr.DataArray(
    np.random.randn(365, 10), [('date', time), ('stock', list('abcdefghij'))])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# create regression result dateframe
params = pd.DataFrame(index=X.date, columns=X.factor)
residuals = pd.DataFrame(index=X.date, columns=X.symbol)

# get the datetimeindex
idx_date = y.get_index('date')
idx_symbol = X.get_index('symbol')

for dt in y.date.values:
    logger.debug('regression on %s', dt)
    cur_date = pd.Timestamp(dt)
    # get the position of current date
    dt_pos = idx_date.get_loc(cur_date)
    if dt_pos == 0:
        continue
    dt_pre_pos = dt_pos - 1
    # symbols having valid value(not nan)
    s = X[:, dt_pre_pos].notnull().all(axis=0)
    valid_x = X[:, dt_pre_pos, s].symbol.values

    w = y.loc[cur_date].notnull()
    valid_y = y.loc[cur_date, w].symbol.values

    valid_symbol = np.intersect1d(valid_x, valid_y)
    try:
        model = sm.RLM(
            y.loc[cur_date, valid_symbol].values,
            X.isel(
                date=dt_pre_pos,
                symbol=idx_symbol.get_indexer(valid_symbol)).values.T,
            M=sm.robust.norms.HuberT())
        results = model.fit()
    except ValueError:
        continue
    params.loc[cur_date] = results.params
    residuals.loc[cur_date, valid_symbol] = results.resid
```